# Zoom desktop tool for Ubuntu 14

Tags: accessibility, zooming

I need a **"zoom tool" for the entire screen** because I want to control a bar with the mouse  (time bar, like youtube) from an web-based audio player. The problem is that this player is too small and **when I try to zoom-in (with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel)**, all characters, pictures are zoomed in, but not the Audio Player (**it keeps its size**).

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance. I have Ubuntu 14.04 with a Nvidia and I use the audio player normally within Firefox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **Compiz Settings Manager** for this.

```
 sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run it from the Dash and navigate to  **Enhanced Zoom Desktop**.

Enable it by putting the tick. You can put the keys bindings for Zooming in and Zooming out.

[image]

---

---

**For Ubuntu 16.04**

---

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

The terminal opens, type

```
apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Go to Ubuntu icon on Top Left corner of desktop

[image]

Click on it and type compiz

[image]

Click on the compiz icon that appers in the window

The following window opens:

[image]

Click on OK

Go to Accebility --> Enhanced Zoom Desktop --> Tick the box

[image]

Click on Enhanced Zoom Desktop

[image]

Click on Zoom In Key --> Disabled

[image]

Tick the box Enabled

[image]

Click on Grab Key Combination

[image]

Press together

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

[image]

Click on OK

[image]

Click on Zoom Out Key --> Disabled

[image]

Tick on the box Enabled

[image]

Click on Grab Key Combination

[image]

Press  together

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

[image]

Click on OK

[image]

Close the window

[image]

From now on

to Zoom In press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

and to Zoom Out press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

Comment: Every time I checked the box in Compiz it was automatically unchecking with no explanation. Enabling other plugins worked fine.. Found [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=949935) which suggested logging out and logging in. After restarting my computer, it worked.