# How to adjust the font size in Ubuntu browser?

Tags: browser

Before you flag my question as already answered, please note that I am try to see the text in "Ubuntu Browser," not Chrome or Firefox, etc. Ubuntu Browser has a desktop icon that is a blue map of the world with a compass needle overlay. I intalled it from Ubuntu Software.
The text in Ubuntu Browser is too small for me to see using a 24 inch monitor.  I can adjust the font in Chromium and Firefox and on the Ubuntu desktop and system. 
I can not find a way to adjust the font in the web browser named "Ubuntu Browser." Ubuntu Browser may be a newer app for Ubuntu 16.04.
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Ubuntu browser zooms at this point.

Its a version of very lightweight browser called Oxide (https://launchpad.net/webbrowser-app) and this issue is a known bug in Oxide (https://bugs.launchpad.net/oxide/+bug/1447395).

There are tweaks and hacks for zooming/magnifying the screen ([Zoom desktop tool for Ubuntu 14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593656/zoom-desktop-tool-for-ubuntu-14)) but I doubt these will satisfy you.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to share your insight! I never would have been able to switch to Ubuntu from Windows without you and others helping me.

Comment: You're welcome. Whenever someone helps don't forget to check that their answer is helpful.  It marks the question as answered.